# How can I sync Mist on a connection with a firewall?

Tags: go-ethereum, synchronization

I'm running Ubuntu Gnome 16.10 with the latest version of Mist installed. Whenever I run Mist at home, syncing works without a hitch. But when I run it at school, Mist opens but shows 0 peers. When I run Geth Console it shows

```
I0113 09:13:51.612062 ethdb/database.go:83] Allotted 128MB cache and 1024 file handles to /home/rthimmiah/.ethereum/geth/chaindata
I0113 09:13:51.674424 ethdb/database.go:176] closed db:/home/rthimmiah/.ethereum/geth/chaindata
I0113 09:13:51.674667 node/node.go:176] instance: Geth/v1.5.6-stable-2a609af5/linux/go1.7.3
I0113 09:13:51.674678 ethdb/database.go:83] Allotted 128MB cache and 1024 file handles to /home/rthimmiah/.ethereum/geth/chaindata
I0113 09:13:51.727646 eth/backend.go:191] Protocol Versions: [63 62], Network Id: 1
I0113 09:13:51.727971 eth/backend.go:219] Chain config: {ChainID: 1 Homestead: 1150000 DAO: 1920000 DAOSupport: true EIP150: 2463000 EIP155: 2675000 EIP158: 2675000}
I0113 09:13:51.728565 core/blockchain.go:216] Last header: #2985964 [5437fb18…] TD=118542923779659614825
I0113 09:13:51.728579 core/blockchain.go:217] Last block: #2985964 [5437fb18…] TD=118542923779659614825
I0113 09:13:51.728590 core/blockchain.go:218] Fast block: #2985964 [5437fb18…] TD=118542923779659614825
I0113 09:13:51.729683 p2p/server.go:340] Starting Server
I0113 09:13:53.854931 p2p/discover/udp.go:227] Listening, enode://4f57b528454642e159a55c637426e8cacb1e343d6f7854b4a872b111235ca42b43b5e50a8feb9d1ab092eef222c12a622d34406d2ba8d152eb78bd3673f64915@[::]:30303
I0113 09:13:53.856099 p2p/server.go:608] Listening on [::]:30303
I0113 09:13:53.873374 node/node.go:341] IPC endpoint opened: /home/rthimmiah/.ethereum/geth.ipc
Welcome to the Geth JavaScript console!
```

Then when I run > eth.syncing it returns false. 
I ran netstat -atun to check what stuff is blocked and not blocked, and it returned

```
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address Foreign Address State 
tcp 0 0 0.0.0.0:5355 0.0.0.0:* LISTEN 
tcp 0 0 127.0.1.1:53 0.0.0.0:* LISTEN 
tcp 0 0 127.0.0.53:53 0.0.0.0:* LISTEN 
tcp 0 0 127.0.0.1:631 0.0.0.0:* LISTEN 
tcp 0 1 10.1.6.226:54236 40.115.22.134:443 FIN_WAIT1 
tcp 0 0 10.1.6.226:59236 178.62.108.238:443 ESTABLISHED
tcp 0 0 10.1.6.226:35378 216.58.197.45:443 ESTABLISHED
tcp 0 0 10.1.6.226:37230 74.125.130.189:443 ESTABLISHED
tcp 0 0 10.1.6.226:46520 216.58.197.37:443 ESTABLISHED
tcp 0 0 10.1.6.226:50688 98.137.201.232:443 TIME_WAIT 
tcp 0 1 10.1.6.226:34212 40.100.16.18:443 FIN_WAIT1 
tcp 0 0 10.1.6.226:48980 31.13.93.36:443 TIME_WAIT 
tcp 0 0 10.1.6.226:39400 216.58.197.74:443 ESTABLISHED
tcp 0 1 10.1.6.226:38028 151.101.1.69:443 FIN_WAIT1 
tcp 0 0 10.1.6.226:42616 216.58.197.35:443 ESTABLISHED
tcp 0 0 10.1.6.226:44638 216.58.197.36:443 ESTABLISHED
tcp 0 0 10.1.6.226:34132 216.58.197.46:443 ESTABLISHED
tcp 0 0 10.1.6.226:46758 198.252.206.25:443 ESTABLISHED
tcp 0 0 10.1.6.226:36106 74.125.158.10:443 ESTABLISHED
tcp 0 0 10.1.6.226:32772 74.125.68.188:443 ESTABLISHED
tcp 0 0 10.1.6.226:50686 98.137.201.232:443 ESTABLISHED
tcp 0 1 10.1.6.226:41742 74.125.68.189:443 FIN_WAIT1 
tcp 38 0 10.1.6.226:46084 74.201.154.115:443 CLOSE_WAIT 
tcp 0 0 10.1.6.226:56990 40.115.22.134:443 ESTABLISHED
tcp 0 211 10.1.6.226:48978 31.13.93.36:443 FIN_WAIT1 
tcp 0 257 10.1.6.226:53948 31.13.78.13:443 ESTABLISHED
tcp 0 0 10.1.6.226:34114 216.58.197.46:443 ESTABLISHED
tcp 0 0 10.1.6.226:56988 40.115.22.134:443 ESTABLISHED
tcp 0 1 10.1.6.226:57302 172.217.24.234:443 FIN_WAIT1 
tcp 0 0 10.1.6.226:54124 74.125.68.189:443 ESTABLISHED
tcp 0 1 10.1.6.226:36536 216.58.196.206:443 FIN_WAIT1 
tcp 0 0 10.1.6.226:52766 23.36.38.3:443 ESTABLISHED
tcp 0 0 10.1.6.226:52768 23.36.38.3:443 TIME_WAIT 
tcp 0 0 10.1.6.226:35376 216.58.197.45:443 ESTABLISHED
tcp 0 0 10.1.6.226:43330 198.252.206.25:443 ESTABLISHED
tcp 0 0 10.1.6.226:34592 216.58.197.46:443 ESTABLISHED
tcp 1 1 10.1.6.226:54238 40.115.22.134:443 LAST_ACK 
tcp 0 0 10.1.6.226:60712 74.201.154.135:443 ESTABLISHED
tcp 0 0 10.1.6.226:58372 172.217.26.206:443 ESTABLISHED
tcp 0 0 10.1.6.226:54904 198.252.206.25:443 ESTABLISHED
tcp 0 0 10.1.6.226:49014 13.107.42.11:443 ESTABLISHED
tcp 0 0 10.1.6.226:35328 216.58.220.46:443 ESTABLISHED
tcp6 0 0 :::5355 :::* LISTEN 
tcp6 0 0 ::1:631 :::* LISTEN 
udp 0 0 0.0.0.0:631 0.0.0.0:* 
udp 0 0 0.0.0.0:45758 0.0.0.0:* 
udp 0 0 0.0.0.0:5353 0.0.0.0:* 
udp 0 0 0.0.0.0:5353 0.0.0.0:* 
udp 0 0 0.0.0.0:5353 0.0.0.0:* 
udp 0 0 0.0.0.0:5355 0.0.0.0:* 
udp 0 0 0.0.0.0:36003 0.0.0.0:* 
udp 0 0 127.0.1.1:53 0.0.0.0:* 
udp 0 0 127.0.0.53:53 0.0.0.0:* 
udp 0 0 0.0.0.0:68 0.0.0.0:* 
udp6 0 0 :::58083 :::* 
udp6 0 0 :::5353 :::* 
udp6 0 0 :::5353 :::* 
udp6 0 0 :::5355 :::*
```

Is there any solution to get Mist to sync without having to use a VPN?